# AngularJS Logout using $http then redirect

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, angular-ui-router

Right so I have a little dilemma here :).

I'm working on a project that is built with angularjs and Laravel. Login is done with laravel which is out of AngularJs "scope", should I say.

So in Front End I do not see that page.

What I'm trying to do is use $http get method to get /logout (handled by laravel again). On success redirect user to /login.

So what I was thinking of doing is:

```
$rootScope.logout = function () {

        $http.get('/logout', function (response) {
            console.log('redirect');
            $window.location.href('/login');
        });
    };
```

But doesn't seem to work for some reason. Suggestions? /logout clears all sessions etc, which is out of my "jurisdiction" :)

Btw I'm also using UI-router.

Comment: You have html5mode enabled?

Comment: Yes I do, could that be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `location.replace` should solve your issue.

```
$rootScope.logout = function () {

    $http.get('/logout', function (response) {
        console.log('redirect');
        var origin = $window.location.origin;
        $window.location.replace(origin + '/login');
    });
};
```

**UPDATE** : 
In case you have defined a route for logout page.

$rootScope.logout = function () {

```
    $http.get('/logout', function (response) {
        console.log('redirect');
        $state.go('logout');
    });
};
```

But keep in mind, you should have `logout` state in such case.

Comment: Right, this makes sense. 1 thing, when I try and get /logout in Inspector (Network tab) I see logout being called, which returns 302 Found. But then right after that call I get another call to the app. Hard to explain. I think the redirect isnt happening for some reason. Could it be UI-Router config ($urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');)?

Comment: Yes, could be. But if you have predefined route for your `/logout` page, I am going to update my answer for such case.

Comment: Hmm.. :/ /logout is all laravel. I created a state in UI Router logout but I probably need to ask BE dev to redirect to login after session has been cleared. Not 100% sure

Comment: I'll check this now. 2 min :) Thx for your answers

Comment: If `logout` page is hosted like a separate page, just use the first strategy. And try to play around with `otherwise`, maybe it is broke your process.